# How to statistically compare two contour plots

Tags: geometry, statistics, matlab, image-processing

What are the ways to compare two different maps? I was thinking of taking the matrices of each map and then quantify their spatial differences by plotting the map of the differences of the two matrices. Are there any other ways to check how similar they are/how much they differ?

[image]

Comment: You clearly need to define what is similarity. One way is to calculate the "distance" between the two images by computing RMS.

Comment: I want to check their similarity with a specific metrics, for example to compare the noise or pollution exposure in each location of the two maps . I will try to check RMS, never heard before thanks.

Comment: RMS measure is a typical means to evaluate noise impact. Be aware that the noise structure is important - white or colored. May be shade could have an impact, and than you want to use some filtering. Note that filter might add bias...